# How do I reorder a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to do an assignment about Linked List, unfortunately, I cannot post my code online. But the general problem goes like this:

I have a linked list of organisms:
list -> Zebra -> Hyena -> Lion -> grass

But I want the list to display in order (food chain):
orderedList -> Lion -> Hyena -> Zebra -> grass

Also, I may add an organism to the list like

```
list.add("T-Rex");
```

So then my desired outcome should be 
orderedList -> T-Rex -> Lion -> Hyena -> Zebra -> grass

How do add organisms and then order them in such a way that it displays a hierarchy? There is a limited number of organism I can put down, so I know exactly where to put them. For example, I knew that if I put T-Rex, it will always be on top of the Lion, Hyena will always be earlier than Grass... and so on..  I've been trying to find tutorials on YouTube and Google but they were mostly sorting numbers or Strings alphabetically, which I don't think really helps my problem.

I would appreciate any help since this is my first time dealing linked list.

Comment: I guess you'd use an integer to represent how high each species is in the hierarchy, then hopefully the sorting by number tutorial would help.

Comment: In such cases, Priority Queue is for the rescue, as number of organism is limited and you already know the names, give them a priority according to the food chain order like T-Rex will have priority 1,Lion 2,Hyena-3  and so on and then apply min priority queue,hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you guys! I looked up Priority Queue and I think it should help!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
add(int index, E element);
```

It inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list and shifts the element currently at that position. So as you know the positions of elements you can add new on at the desired position.

```
list.add(0,"T-Rex");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map every animal in your list with some kind of hierarchy level value, `e.g: T-Rex - 1, Lion - 2, ...`. Then you can put all values to the LinkedList and sort with custom Comparator, or as an alternative to the Priority Queue.

As a result, you will have ordered a hierarchy in your list.
Example:

```
class Organism {
    String name;
    int level;

    public Organism(String name, int level) {
         ...
    }
}
PrioriQueue q = new PriorityQueue(...custom_comparator...);
q.add(...add_all_organism_here....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

Create class Organism which implement Comparable and have a custom natural ordering specific for your class.

```
public class Organism implements Comparable<Organism> {
    private Integer hierarchy;
    private String name;

    public Organism (String nameArg, Integer hierarchyArg) {
         name = nameArg;
         hierarchy = hierarchyArg;
    }

    public Integer getHierarchy() {
        return hierarchy;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Organism a) 
    {
        return this.getHierarchy().compareTo( a.getHierarchy() );
    }
}
```

Now I can add in the list in any order:

```
//Put a big gap between the numbers so if you need later you can add more organisms in between 
list.add(new Organism("T-Rex", 1000));
list.add(new Organism("Zebra", 10));
list.add(new Organism("Lion", 500));
list.add(new Organism("Hyena", 200));
```

And then you can use Java to sort them:

```
// Java old way of sorting. It will modify the 'list' itself
Collections.sort(list); 

//Java 8+ way of sorting. It does not modify the 'list' but create a new one.
List<String> sortedList = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Documentation for Comparable interface:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Good luck!