# Sort a list - string element

Tags: java, string, list, sorting

I have an object list like this:

```
List <myObjectModel> list = new ArrayList ();
```

myObjectModel is composed of two strings (name and placement)

In this list there are the following elements in this order:

```
myObjectModel ("jeans", "B2")

myObjectModel ("jonnhy", "A1")

myObjectModel ("amanda", "H12")

myObjectModel ("samy", "A2")

myObjectModel ("bertrand", "G6")
```

I would like to sort my list on the second string (A1 jonnhy, A2 samy, B2 jean, G6 bertrand, H12 amanda)

Is it possible with "sort"?

Thank you

Comment: Just before hour I answer very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135759/6068297 Just change the property and the name of the class to yours. Also change the to the types which you are using. I hope it help you!

Comment: something like `myList.sort((model1, model2) -> model1.getSecondString().compareTo(model2.getSecondString()));`

Answer (score 0):

Using sort method of List:

```
 myObjectModelList.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObjectModel::getProperty2));
```

Using Java 8 stream API:

```
List<MyObjectModel > myObjectModelList = list.stream()
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObjectModel::getProperty2))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about retrieving the list sorted from the database then use 
`@OrderBy`

like this

```
@OrderBy("second_string ASC")
List <myObjectModel> list = new ArrayList ();
```

and `second_string` here is the column name in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAVA Stream API to solve this problem. But i think it is not efficient. I suggest Comparator method. I write codes as below,

Main Method

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <myObjectModel> list = new ArrayList<> ();
        list.add(new myObjectModel ("jeans", "B2"));
        list.add(new myObjectModel ("jonnhy", "A1"));
        list.add(new myObjectModel ("amanda", "H12"));
        list.add(new myObjectModel ("samy", "A2"));
        list.add(new myObjectModel ("bertrand", "G6"));
        
        list.sort(new myObjectComparator());
        
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Java Model Class

```html
public class myObjectModel{
    public String name;
    public String placement;
    
    public myObjectModel(String name, String placement){
        this.name = name;
        this.placement = placement;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name+", "+this.placement;
    } 
}
```

Comparator Class

```html
import java.util.Comparator;

public class myObjectComparator implements Comparator<myObjectModel>{

    @Override
    public int compare(myObjectModel o1, myObjectModel o2) {
        return o1.placement.compareTo(o2.placement);
    }
    
}
```